# Problems calling jQuery function from within normal JavaScript function

Tags: jquery, accordion, javascript

Tried looking at other solutions but they don't quite answer my question so here goes.

The code below shows me declaring an anonymous function to run when the document is ready which contains another function relating to a plugin which creates a horrizontal accordion.
That function takes in certain properties and one property, eventAction, allows you to define a function and I've tried to call the jQuery AJAX load function but it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".accordion").hrzAccordion({
            openOnLoad: 6,
            fixedWidth: 648,
            eventAction: function(){
                $("#accordionContent0").load("hips.html");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I place the line $("#accordionContent0").load("hips.html"); outside of the $(".accordion").hrzAccordion function, but still with the ready function, it works fine.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong by calling the load function inside the other function?

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, are you sure the evenetAction function actually gets invoked? If you set a breakpoint or insert a console.log() line, does it trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".accordion").hrzAccordion({
            openOnLoad: 6,
            fixedWidth: 648,
            eventAction: function(){
                loadAcc($(".accordion"));
            }
        });
    });

function loadAcc(acc) {
  $("#accordionContent0").load("hips.html");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd clean your code up if I could. You might want to check out PreCode Code Snippet Manager found on codeplex: http://fiftyeightbits-precode-code-window-plugi.software.informer.com/download/

Comment: Please what does the software do?